# calling a function indirectly from main with an particular format output

Tags: c++, function

Here is my program below.

```
  void fun1(void);
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    cout<<"In main"<<endl;
    atexit(fun1);              //atexit calls the function at the end of main
    cout<<"Exit main"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
  void fun1(void)
  {
    cout<<"fun1 executed"<<endl;
  }
```

The output is

```
 In main
 Exit main
 fun1 executed
```

But I intend the output like this:

```
 In main
 fun1 executed
 Exit main
```

I don't want to call "fun1" function directly or use any other functions which would call my function "fun1".

Is there any way I can acheive this this output? Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Could I ask, why do you need to call fun1 indirectly? and would an aliasing/macro/define solution suit your needs?

Comment: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) do you need this?

Comment: How should any mechanism know that you are about to exit soon and want something to be automagically executed before your cout statement? Using raii I could understand on exiting main, but before that cout seems really silly

Answer (score 2):

**No.** <sup>†</sup>

Only `atexit` and static object destruction happen "on their own", and both these things occur after returning from `main`.

And this makes sense, when you think about it: something that should occur during `main` should be written in `main`. If you need a function to be invoked at a given time, write it into your program. This is what you write the program for. `main` is for your program.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Probably, with a "trick" or "hack" that'll get you fired from my team.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack using a scope:

```
#include <iostream>

class call_on_destructed {
private:
    void (*m_callee)();
public:
    call_on_destructed(void (*callee)()): m_callee(callee) {}
    ~call_on_destructed() {
        m_callee();
    }
};

void fun() {
    std::cout << "fun\n";
}

int main() {
    {
        call_on_destructed c(&fun);
        std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"Exit main"<<std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
In main
fun
Exit main
```

The scope end causes the class destructor to be invoked, which in turn calls the fun function, registered within the class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I've never been a team player anyways ;)

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like:

```
  void fun1(void)
  {
    std::cout << "fun1 executed" << std::endl;
  }

  void call(void f())
  {
      f();
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
    call(fun1);              //call calls the given function directly
    std::cout << "Exit main" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `or use any other functions which would call my function "fun1"`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: , our function doesn't mention `fun1`, we take just a function pointer (as `atexit` does).

Comment: By that logic you might as well `#define LOLJAROD fun1` and write `LOLJAROD()`. Not really useful to solving the OP's problem if you're just going to quibble over the names of things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `LOLJAROD` refers to `fun1` whereas `call` and `atexit` not. My solution is the equivalent of `atexit` which calls the given function directly (which seems to be what OP asked for)... if you want use macro for my solution use something like `#define CALL(FUNC) (FUNC())` (no mention to `fun1`).

Comment: `atexit(fun1)` doesn't "refer to `fun1`"? `call(fun1)` doesn't "refer to `fun1`"? Guess I missed something.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `atexit` and `call` code doesn't refer to `fun1`, we call them with `fun1` as *parameter*... Why not do the same comment for your coworker response ? (because he renamed `fun1` to `func` ;) ?)

Comment: How is using `fun1` as a function argument not "referring to `fun1`"?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As I understand OP, he doesn't want `void f() { fun1(); } void f2() { f(); /*which call fun1*/ }`. If he doesn't want a solution where `fun1` appears, I don't understand what OP wants (hack to take address of `fun1` ?).

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, if you want to have your function executed, something is going to call it! That is, calling your function without calling your function won't work. `atexit()` is also just calling your function: you register what's being called eventually.

From the sounds of it, your assignment asks to pass off a function object off and have that facility call your function. For example, you could use a function caller:

```
template <typename F>
void caller(F f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "entering main\n";
    caller(fun1);
    std::cout << "exiting main()\n";
}
```

Clearly, `caller()` does call `fun1` although without mentioning that name.

Comment: `or use any other functions which would call my function "fun1"`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Seems I made wrong allegations earlier (and removed the offending comments). To respond go your comment, though: there is no function called which calls "fun1" as requested! There is function which calls a function object as is done by `atexit()`: I think that fits the description.